# Code behind in aspx sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parameters, webforms

May I know how could I pass the value of driver from code behind and throw into the query in aspx file ?

Here is my aspx part:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="cs_sc" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MIMConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cash_Sales] WHERE [driver] = @driver">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="driver" Direction="Input" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    driver = driverUpdateBox.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cs_sc.SelectParameters["driver"].DefaultValue = driverUpdateBox.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cash_Sales] WHERE [driver] = <%$ this.driver %>">
```

Comment: This would allow a SQL injection attack.

Comment: How? The code is being executed in the server only, `this` references the current aspx page, `driver` references a property in the aspx page and all this is embedded in a `<asp:SqlDataSource`

Comment: this.driver = driverUpdateBox.SelectedItem.Text comes from the client, the concatenation in = <%$ this.driver %> adds the non-trustworthy string from the client to the trusted sql on the server. so a client manipulating the client value to "0;drop table users;" Though it now occurs to me that the <%$ might something useful, I don't know that syntax. However the very idea of using asp:SqlDataSource is not a solution I would allow in my team, it's just too smelly :-/

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataSource has SelectParameters property, use it like this :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cs_sc.SelectParameters["driver"] = driverUpdateBox.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```